# Compile rosmatlab with winros on Windows 7 (catkin_make)

Tags: ros, catkin-make, winros, rosmatlab, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi again,
I finally got to compile winros with another Boost version (in the end it was just ridiculously easy...), but now I don't know how to substitute the command

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$MATLAB_ROOT/ros/groovy -DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=ON -DBOOST_ROOT=$MATLAB_ROOT/ros/groovy install
```

described [here](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/rosmatlab/wiki/Installation#4-rosmatlab-and-cpp_introspection) with winros_make, since I don't know how to pass those arguments to winros_make so that it redirects them to the internal call to cmake.

Is there anybody who solved this or has suggestions? I read about putting the arguments in either a configure.cmake or findboost.cmake file, but since I'm not yet familiar with cmake, I wasn't able to handle that by now.

Greets and big thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147916/compile-rosmatlab-with-winros-on-windows-7-(catkin_make)/) by [bnm-rc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11866/bnm-rc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2014-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can see [here](http://wiki.ros.org/win_ros/hydro/Msvc Compiled SDK) the three steps for a winros_xxx process. After the  [winros_init_build](http://wiki.ros.org/win_ros/hydro/Msvc Compiled SDK#Build) step you'll have a config.cmake file which you can edit, change and add any new variables for the cmake build you want (this is equivalent to piling them onto the catkin_make or cmake command line).

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bnm-rc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11866/bnm-rc/) on 2014-04-22**:
I probably missed the --install step, but already worked around this by calling nmake install from within the build library. Thanks a lot anyway!